# xslt dynamic xpath Saxon EE

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have following xml:

```
    ...                    
    <peci:Address peci:isDeleted="1">
        <peci:Usage_Type>WORK</peci:Usage_Type>
        <peci:Address_Line_1>AMEC</peci:Address_Line_1>
        <peci:Address_Line_2>2020 Winston Park Drive, Suite
            700</peci:Address_Line_2>
        <peci:City>Oakville</peci:City>
        <peci:Postal_Code>L6H 6X7</peci:Postal_Code>
        <peci:Country>CA</peci:Country>
        <peci:Country_Region>ON</peci:Country_Region>
        <peci:State_Province>Ontario</peci:State_Province>
    </peci:Address>
    <peci:Address peci:isAdded="1">
        <peci:Usage_Type>WORK</peci:Usage_Type>
        <peci:Address_Line_1>639 5th Avenue SW</peci:Address_Line_1>
        <peci:Address_Line_2>Suite 1410</peci:Address_Line_2>
        <peci:City>Calgary</peci:City>
        <peci:Postal_Code>T2P 0M9</peci:Postal_Code>
        <peci:Country>CA</peci:Country>
        <peci:Country_Region>AB</peci:Country_Region>
        <peci:State_Province>Alberta</peci:State_Province>
    <peci:Address>
        <peci:Usage_Type>HOME</peci:Usage_Type>
        <peci:Address_Line_1>88 Bridge Cres.</peci:Address_Line_1>
        <peci:City>Burlington</peci:City>
        <peci:Postal_Code>L7L 0A3</peci:Postal_Code>
        <peci:Country>CA</peci:Country>
        <peci:Country_Region>ON</peci:Country_Region>
        <peci:State_Province>Ontario</peci:State_Province>
   </peci:Address>
   <peci:Email/>
...
```

I iterate through  the document and when find added node

```
peci:isAdded="1"
```

I check whether presiding node has the same element and has been deleted

```
peci:isDeleted="1"
```

if that is the case I would like to iterate through  child elements and list all elements that are different (here everything but country)

I would like to use that  for different nodes so I cannot use hard coded list of elements and when iterate through added element I dont know how to access the corresponding element in the proceeding sibling. It try sth like:

```
<xsl:when
    test="../@peci:isAdded and ../preceding-sibling::*[../local-name()]/@peci:isDeleted">
    <xsl:variable name="oldValueLocations" select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="../preceding-sibling::*[../local-name()][@peci:isDeleted]/$oldValueLocations"/>                    
</xsl:when>
```

I would expect

```
 <out:Row xtt:separator="," xtt:quotes="always">
        <out:PayGroupCode>93JH</out:PayGroupCode>
        <out:LegacyID>93JH000660265</out:LegacyID>
        <out:WorkdayID>660265</out:WorkdayID>
        <out:Name>SixWFNLastname SixWFNFirstname</out:Name>
        <out:Status>Active</out:Status>
        <out:Transaction>CHANGE</out:Transaction>
        <out:Process_Type>DTA</out:Process_Type>
        <out:Type>Address</out:Type>
        <out:SubType>Country_Region</out:SubType>
        <out:Effective_Date>2017-03-06</out:Effective_Date>
        <out:Old_Value>ON</out:Old_Value>
        <out:New_Value>AB</out:New_Value>
    </out:Row>
```

but instead I get

```
 <out:Row xtt:separator="," xtt:quotes="always">
        <out:PayGroupCode>93JH</out:PayGroupCode>
        <out:LegacyID>93JH000660265</out:LegacyID>
        <out:WorkdayID>660265</out:WorkdayID>
        <out:Name>SixWFNLastname SixWFNFirstname</out:Name>
        <out:Status>Active</out:Status>
        <out:Transaction>CHANGE</out:Transaction>
        <out:Process_Type>DTA</out:Process_Type>
        <out:Type>Address</out:Type>
        <out:SubType>Country_Region</out:SubType>
        <out:Effective_Date>2017-03-06</out:Effective_Date>
        <out:Old_Value>WORK AMEC 2020 Winston Park Drive, Suite 700 Oakville L6H 6X7 CA ON
            Ontario</out:Old_Value>
        <out:New_Value>AB</out:New_Value>
    </out:Row>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know about `local-name()` and predicate it seems selecting `*[local-name() = $oldValueLocations]` seems obvious to select elements of that name, probably with your other path prefixed (although I don't understand what the `[../local-name()]` is supposed to do).

Comment: I think that local name is the same for <peci:Address peci:isAdded="1">
 and <peci:Address peci:isDeleted="1"> but cannot assign it to $oldValueLocations

Comment: You might want to edit your question and add a minimal but complete sample of input you have and output you want. I thought so far that the problem is about identifying the various child elements of the `peci:Address` elements. Are the element having those `peci:isAdded/isDeleted` attributes present on different elements as well?

Comment: instead of this:
<out:Old_Value>WORK AMEC 2020 Winston Park Drive, Suite 700 Oakville L6H 6X7 CA ON
            Ontario</out:Old_Value>
I would like to have a proper value which is region in this case.
 <out:Old_Value>ON</out:Old_Value>

Comment: Try to edit your question to provide minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT and output you want to allow us to reproduce and then hopefully fix the problem.